# Sidebar covers over textarea when improving tag excerpt edit

Tags: bug, review, design, suggested-edits

In [this review](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13712) I clicked "Improve edit", which gave me this:

[image]

As you can see, the "What is a tag wiki excerpt" sidebar covers the textarea.